# How to aggregate command hardware interfaces in ros_control?

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-control, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know what workarounds can be used to allow a controller to command more than one hardware interface in ros_control. The hardware interfaces could be homogeneous or heterogeneous (e.g. `VelocityJointInterface` + `PositionJointInterface` + `MyCustomInterface`). I am looking for a solution that does not involve creating a new hardware interface with gigantic handles. There is a workaround [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues/75) for the case where only one hardware interface sends commands, but it might not work for our particular case.

One of our applications for this is a mobile manipulator where the arm has velocity and position hardware interfaces, and the base has a velocity hardware interface. We would like to control both the arm and the base within the same controller.

To get familiar with ros_control, we developed the control architecture for the arm first. The `RobotHW` specialization has a `VelocityJointInterface` and a `PosVelJointInterface` for visual servoing/joystick and trajectory tracking control modes, respectively. The design of the architecture is such that several components (e.g. arm + base) can be aggregated in a single `RobotHW` specialization. Now we are facing the difficulty of aggregating hardware interfaces at the controller level. So I would like to know what other people have done on similar scenarios.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204084/how-to-aggregate-command-hardware-interfaces-in-ros_control?/) by [Daniel L](https://answers.ros.org/users/21389/daniel-l/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIURC, you want to send commands to different interfaces from a single controller, but there is one interface associated to each resource (eg. joint). This is currently not well supported, and would require (C++ and ROS) API changes to be done correctly.

That being said, you could hack your way around by deriving your controller from [`controller_interface::ControllerBase`](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/controller_interface/html/c++/classcontroller__interface_1_1ControllerBase.html) (as opposed to `controller_interface::Controller<T>`). The upside is that you get access to a `RobotHW*`, (as opposed to a particular interface), hence to all the robot's resources. The downside is that the [getHardwareInterfaceType](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/controller_interface/html/c++/classcontroller__interface_1_1ControllerBase.html#aa2908562c2d435458ae257d7431ab198) method, which you must implement, assumes a single HW interface. Resource conflict handling [might not work correctly](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/controller_manager/src/controller_manager.cpp#L251) in such a case, I haven't checked the implications in detail.

---

This is not what you are trying to do, but I add it here for completeness. If you want to attack the same resource from different HW interfaces, you can implement a custom [checkForConflict(...)](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/robot_hw.h#L73) method for your hardware abstraction, and override the default exclusive resource usage policy.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel L](https://answers.ros.org/users/21389/daniel-l/) on 2015-03-05**:
Thanks for replying. I went through the code in `ControllerManager::ControllerManager` and checkForConflict(...), and it seems that this would work. The first only uses the hardware_interface type as a string for reporting purposes. The second uses ControllerInfo::resources.

**Comment by [Daniel L](https://answers.ros.org/users/21389/daniel-l/) on 2015-03-05**:
Would there be other parts of the code where the hardware_interface type string is used?

**Comment by [Andreas Hermann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22601/andreas-hermann/) on 2016-02-22**:
Just to see, if I get this right:
I will NOT be able to have a hardware_interface for my device A and another hardware_interface for my device B and have them controlled in sync by one single trajectory controller? So I have to aggregate ALL different drivers (CANOpen, Serial, ...) in one interface?